# Having trouble styling a tooltip Header to 'pull-left'

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

For the following piechart, I have a tooltip that is structured in table format and displays on a hover event.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 500,
            x: function(d){return d.key;},
            y: function(d){return d.y;},
            noData: '0 incidents',
            color:['#CE1B1F', '#FFC455', '#00A6CD'],
            showLabels: false,
            duration: 500,
            labelThreshold: 0.01,
            labelSunbeamLayout: true,
            legend: {
                margin: {
                    top: 5,
                    right: 35,
                    bottom: 5,
                    left: 0
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
            contentGenerator: function (e) {
              var series = e.series[0];
              if (series.value === null) return;

              var header = 
                "<thead>" + 
                  "<tr>" +
                    "<td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div></td>" +
                    "<td class='key'><strong>" + series.key + "</strong></td>" +
                  "</tr>" + 
                "</thead>";

              var rows = 
                "<tr>" +
                  "<td class='key'>" + series.key + '- #3: ' + "</td>" +
                  "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute1 + "</td>" + 
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                  "<td class='key'>" + series.key + '- #5: ' + "</td>" +
                  "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute2 + "</td>" + 
                "</tr>";

              return "<table>" +
                  header +
                  "<tbody>" + 
                    rows + 
                  "</tbody>" +
                "</table>";
            } 
          }                

        }
    };

    $scope.data = [
        {
            key: "CAT I",
            y: 2,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT I",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT I"
        },
        {
            key: "CAT II",
            y: 1,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT II",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT II"
        },
        {
            key: "CAT III",
            y: 3,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT III",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT III"
        },
    ];
});
```

I'm having trouble making the tooltip Header (series.key) align directly to the right of the series.color property. Right now it's displayed in the center. I tried injecting a pull-left, and a float left, but it doesnt change anything.

Here's a plunkr to show you that tooltip: 
      http://plnkr.co/edit/2SFzP96OIRyGhtM3j5Cp?p=preview

Comment: the tooltip Header is in the 2nd column(td) of the row(tr) and its already left alignedthis is why its not moving the position of header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip is made of a table so what is happening is this:

```
----------------------
Color        | CAT 1
----------------------
CAT III- #3: |         
----------------------
```

Try moving `<strong>" + series.key + "</strong>` into the table row above it after the div like so:

```
<td colspan="2" class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div><strong>" + series.key + "</strong></td>
```

Then remove `<td class='key'><strong>" + series.key + "</strong></td>`

This will allow you to style things the way you want.  The important part is colspan="2"

For reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

```
              var header = 
                "<thead>" + 
                  "<tr>" +
                    "<td colspan='2' class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'><strong>" + series.key + "</strong></div></td>" +
                  "</tr>" + 
                "</thead>";
```

Comment: can you show this in a plunkr? I'm having trouble replicating this

Comment: I tried inserting that snippet but the tooltip won't display. Did it work for you when you tried it in the plunkr?

Comment: Try this.  I forgot to change the quotes for colspan due to tring already being quoted.  Essentially change colspan="2" to colspan='2'

I updated the last code fragment.

Comment: thats a little better, but now it's overlapping the series.color. See the updated plunkr:  plnkr.co/edit/vtKvxygdFh2WFLJ7vSbX?p=preview

Comment: looks great! is there any way to show a little spacing between the colored box and the series.key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116005/discussion-between-kunal-ojha-and-dottedt).

Comment: Yes but I'm not going to do it for you.  I've done enough.

Here's a hint. Take a look at the style.css everything you need is there.

Comment: I tried adding a 'left' and a 'padding' style, but doesn't space the header :(

Comment: Well, I sort of got it. The only problem is that there is an outer box that shows up now,  if anyone knew how to remove that id appreciate it    http://plnkr.co/edit/cpcfhAK7NIfSakaIqy5t?p=preview

Comment: this is all you needed. 

.left{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}